# Creating matrix for all dates and all users with counts and categories

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2012 and have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CategoryIds](
    [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimDate](
    [Year_Value] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month_Value] [int] NOT NULL
) 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TransactionsData](
    [TransactionId] [int] NOT NULL,
[UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

The data in the tables is like this:

```
Insert into [dbo].[Users]
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
select 3


Insert into [dbo].[CategoryIds]
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
select 5

insert into [dbo].[DimDate]
select 2015, 3 union all
select 2015,4

insert into [dbo].[TransactionsData]
select 1,1,1,'2015-03-01' union all
select 2,1,1,'2015-03-20' union all
select 3,2,5,'2015-03-02' union all
select 4,2,5,'2015-03-05'
```

I would like to have a T-SQL code which produces a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Matrix](
[Year_Value] [int] NOT NULL,
[Month_Value] [int] NOT NULL,
[UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[TransactionCount] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[1] [int] NOT NULL, -- category with id 1
[2] [int] NOT NULL, -- category with id 2
[5] [int] NOT NULL  -- category with id 5 etc
)
```

And the Matrix table contains a record for each user for each Year and Month, regardless whether there were any transactions for that user for that month. If there are no transactions, the Year and month and UserID still exist as records, but the transaction count is 0. The same is valid for the categories: each CategoryId becomes a column of the Matrix table, and in each column there is a count of how many transactions belong to each category per Year, Month and per User. If there are no transactions for a specific user and for specific category, then the value is 0 in the respective column.

What I've tried:

```
select d.*, u.UserId, isnull(t.TransactionId,0) 
from [dbo].[DimDate] d 
outer apply (select UserId from [dbo].[Users]) u 
full outer join [dbo].[TransactionsData] t on u.UserId = t.UserId
```

The data in the Matrix table will look like this, given the data in the tables above:

```
INSERT INTO  [dbo].[Matrix]
SELECT 2015, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2015, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2015, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2015, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2015, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2015, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: I tried this: 
`select d.*, u.UserId, isnull(t.TransactionId,0) from [dbo].[DimDate] d
outer apply (select UserId from  [dbo].[Users]) u
full outer join [dbo].[TransactionsData] t
on u.UserId = t.UserId `

But there are some records missing. The idea is to get all records and then do Pivot for the count of transactions and categories. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Can you post the expected result for your sample data?

Comment: The data in the Matrix table will look like this, given the data in the tables above:
`INSERT INTO  [dbo].[Matrix]
SELECT 2015, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2015, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2015, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2015, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2015, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2015, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a [**dynamic crosstab**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cd87d1/1/0)

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
    a.Year_Value
    , a.Month_Value
    , a.UserId
    , COUNT(td.TransactionId) AS TransactionCount' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'   , SUM(CASE WHEN CategoryId = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CategoryId) + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(CategoryId) + CHAR(10)
FROM CategoryIds

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'FROM (
    SELECT
        u.UserId, dd.Year_Value, m.Month_Value
    FROM(VALUES
        (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
    )m(Month_Value)
    CROSS JOIN(
        SELECT DISTINCT Year_Value FROM DimDate
    )dd
    CROSS JOIN Users u  
) a
LEFT JOIN TransactionsData td
    ON td.UserId = a.UserId
    AND MONTH(td.Date) = a.Month_Value
    AND YEAR(td.Date) = a.Year_Value
GROUP BY
    a.Year_Value, a.Month_Value, a.UserId
ORDER BY
    a.UserId, a.Year_Value, a.Month_Value'

PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

---

The idea is to generate all possible `UserId` - `Year_Value` - `Month_Value` combinations. Then, use the generated combinations and do a `LEFT JOIN` on `TransactionsData`.

Now, for the `CategoryIds` to show as columns, you need to do a conditional aggregation. Here is the non-dynamic solution. This is also the output of `PRINT @sql` command.

```
SELECT
    a.Year_Value
    , a.Month_Value
    , a.UserId
    , COUNT(td.TransactionId) AS TransactionCount
    , SUM(CASE WHEN CategoryId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [1]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN CategoryId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN CategoryId = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [5]
FROM (
    SELECT
        u.UserId, dd.Year_Value, m.Month_Value
    FROM(VALUES
        (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
    )m(Month_Value)
    CROSS JOIN(
        SELECT DISTINCT Year_Value FROM DimDate
    )dd
    CROSS JOIN Users u  
) AS a
LEFT JOIN TransactionsData td
    ON td.UserId = a.UserId
    AND MONTH(td.Date) = a.Month_Value
    AND YEAR(td.Date) = a.Year_Value
GROUP BY
    a.Year_Value, a.Month_Value, a.UserId
ORDER BY
    a.UserId, a.Year_Value, a.Month_Value
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)